# Swap two number in 8085 Microprocessor without using temporary variable

Tags: 8085

Is there any procedure to swap two numbers in microprocessor 8085 with out using any temporary register ? We all know that the same problem in C programming can be done by following manner

```
A=A+B;
B=A-B;
A=A-B;
```

Here 1st and last lines are executable but the 2nd line cannot be implemented in 8085 MP as the result would always be stored in Accumulator. So is there any other possibility to do so?

Comment: Before down vote, please mention the reason.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8085#16-bit_operations) there is an XCHG instruction:

> The XCHG operation exchanges the values of HL and DE.

Comment: Yes that can be done. Keeping (H) and (D) 00h and placing the values in (L) & (E) or vice-versa , the problem could be solved. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to swap numbers without a temporary variable. Well there are a couple of ways you can do so:

1. As you mentioned, you can do so using the addition and subtraction method viz. A = A+B, B = A - B and A = A - B
   However, as you pointed out 8085 uses the accumulator to do the operations so we can implement it a little differently:

   ```
   MVI A, <value 1>
   MVI B, <value 2>
   ADD B
   MOV A,C
   SUB B
   MOV A,B
   MOV C,A
   SUB B
   ```

   Now you will find the values to be exchanged
2. The other way is to use the XCHG command

Answer (score -1):

```
x = x xor y
y = x xor y
x = x xor y
```

Comment: And this does not suffer the same accumulator problem? can XOR be used more freely than ADD/SUB ?

Comment: I don't think so. After all operation arithmetical or logical the result will be stored in Accumulator.